# Nginx rule to rewrite numbers at the end of url

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

I can't find a way to convert this url:

https://domain.com/en/whatever/12345-mylink

to this

https://domain.com/en/whatever/mylink

Thanks for helping me out.

After this I came with this solution but it didn't work:

rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*) ttps://domain.com/$1/$2/$3 permanent;

Because it directs to this now:

ttps://domain.com/12345

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and I can't tell if you want a redirect, a rewrite or what your nginx config looks like for /whatever/mylink.

But, assuming you just want to redirect /whatever/(insert numbers)-mylink to your own site, sans (insert numbers), the following should put you on the right track:

```
location ~ "^/en/whatever/([0-9]+)-mylink" {
     rewrite ^(.*) http://192.168.99.100:8080/en/whatever/mylink;
}
location ~ ^/en/whatever/mylink {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.yahoo.com;
}
```

I spun up a Docker container with nginx. I modified the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file and added those few lines. My docker container was running on that internal IP, so you'd want to adjust for yours.

If you hit /whatever/(as many numbers as you want)-mylink, it will rewrite it to mylink, which just goes to yahoo.

Again, your question was really vague, but I am guessing you want something like that.

Edit:
After reading your comments, it appears you need to capture regex parameters in your re-write. You can do that via $1 for the first, $2 for the second, and so on. Here is an example that will hopefully be more pertinent to your use case. Again this is just hacking on default.conf:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)-mylink http://192.168.99.100:8080/en/$1/$2/mylink;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ ^/en/whatever/whatevs/mylink {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.yahoo.com;
}
```

If you spin this up and go to /en/whatever/whatevs/12345-mylink, you'll redirect to yahoo.

Comment: Sorry for being vague in my question and thans for your help. What I need is a permanent redirect on these links. Problem is that /en/whatever/ subfolders may be named in many different ways. Don't know if I explain my self, but /en/whatever/ may be /es/cosa/ or many other regular expressions. So "mylink" can be any other word.  Can you help ?  Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to capture regex values with $1, $2, etc